# Erro "Class Swift_KeyCache_SimpleKeyCacheInputStream does not exist"

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando enviar email com Laravel 5.1, mas recebo a mensagem abaixo sempre.

> ReflectionException in DependencyContainer.php line 309: 
>   Class Swift_KeyCache_SimpleKeyCacheInputStream does not exist

Meu arquivo *composer.json* está do seguinte modo:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
      "php": ">=5.5.9",
      "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
      "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "@stable"
  },
  "require-dev": {
      "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
      "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
      "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
      "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
      "classmap": [
          "database"
      ],
      "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app/"
      }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
      "classmap": [
          "tests/TestCase.php"
      ]
  },
  "scripts": {
      "post-install-cmd": [
          "php artisan clear-compiled",
          "php artisan optimize"
      ],
      "pre-update-cmd": [
          "php artisan clear-compiled"
      ],
      "post-update-cmd": [
          "php artisan optimize"
      ],
      "post-root-package-install": [
          "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
      ],
      "post-create-project-cmd": [
          "php artisan key:generate"
      ]
  },
  "config": {
      "preferred-install": "dist"
  }
  }
```

Comment: Use o titulo sempre sobre o problema do código pra facilitar, "enviar email" é apenas o resultado desejado amigo. Editei o titulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema com o seguinte modo: Procurei as classes que estavam faltando no meu projeto na pasta *vendor* e descobri que elas eram um arquivo php em branco, por causa disso baixei no GitHub o projeto do SwiftMailer e copiei as classes que faltavam e o sistema funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Provavelmente você esqueceu de adicionar as dependências ao composer e isto fez que tais arquivos não fossem baixados (não sei ao certo, não tenho familiaridade com o composer)

Answer (score 0):

Entre no arquivo `mail.php` em `app/config/`.

Você preencheu as informações de envio de e-mail nesse arquivo ?

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.one2up.com.br',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => '', 'name' => ''),
'encryption' => '',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
```

Comment: Sim, a minha versão fica em /config/mail.php, não na pasta app. Fora isso, fiz todas as configurações.

Comment: Troque `smtp` por `mail`, então e veja se persiste o erro.

Comment: Troquei e o mesmo erro persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você esqueceu alguma dependência, não sei ao certo.

Se não existir arquivo composer.lock, então o composer irá ler o as tuas dependencias e versões que estão no composer.json e irá criar o arquivo de trava (composer.lock) após executar o comando `update` ou `install`.

Após você editar o teu composer.json rode este comando:

```
php composer.phar update
```

> **Nota:** O Composer irá mostrar um alerta quando executar um comando de instalação acaso o `composer.lock` e `composer.json` não estiverem sincronizados.

Se você quiser atualizar apenas uma dependência, você pode tentar o seguinte comando:

```
php composer.phar update swiftmailer/swiftmailer @stable
```

Comment: Eu já havia feito isso antes, e mesmo assim vinha esta classe vazia. Isto que eu fiz foi a única solução que encontrei.

Comment: @PedroSoares o composer.json e o lock estavam sincronizados? Tentou o comando install primeiro?

Comment: Sim, foi com o install que ele baixou o swiftmailer.

Comment: @PedroSoares então pode ser um problema no repositorio, cria uma issue lá, eu vou acompanhar: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/new

Comment: Já fiz a issue lá.

Comment: @PedroSoares Legal, espero que seja um bug e que possa ser corrigido em breve, fazer atualização manual de dependências é bem complicado :)